# stylesheets not found in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vps

I've got a barebones Rails deployed to a remote server, however, it's not showing any styles. If I check the page source, there's a link to the stylesheet (it uses the twitter bootstrap gem)

```
 <link href="/assets/application-99190f98350e7ed3bb886d20f87bedfd.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
```

but when I click the link, I get a 404 Not Found

http://162.XXX.XXX/assets/application-99190f98350e7ed3bb886d20f87bedfd.css

```
 404 Not Found

nginx/1.4.3
```

It's the same for the javascript.

I'm using NGINX and Unicorn on an ubuntu server, configured according to how Ryan Bates describes in his Railscasts "Deploying to a VPS" http://railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps?view=asciicast. If I view the css file on the remote server, it has all the styles...

Does anyone know what the problem might be?  How would I specify the full path to the stylesheets in the application layout file? would that avoid the problem?

```
/*
  =require twitter-bootstrap-static/bootstrap

  Use Font Awesome icons (default)
  To use Glyphicons sprites instead of Font Awesome, replace with "require twitter-bootstrap-static/sprites"
  =require twitter-bootstrap-static/fontawesome
  */


  html,
      body {
        height: 100%;
       /*   background-color: #;*/
        /* The html and body elements cannot have any padding or margin. */
      }

      /* Wrapper for page content to push down footer */
      #wrap {
        min-height: 100%;
        height: auto !important;
        height: 100%;
        /* Negative indent footer by it's height */
        margin: 0 auto -60px;
      }

      /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
      #push,
      #footer {
        height: 60px;
      }
      #footer {
        background-color: rgb(245, 240, 240);
      }

      /* Lastly, apply responsive CSS fixes as necessary */
      @media (max-width: 767px) {
        #footer {
          margin-left: -20px;
          margin-right: -20px;
          padding-left: 20px;
          padding-right: 20px;
        }
      }

      #wrap > .container {
        padding-top: 60px;
      }

a:visited {
color: #000;
}

ul, menu, dir {
list-style-type: none;
```

Update

```
nginx.conf
upstream unicorn {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.myapp.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80 default deferred;
  # server_name example.com;
  root /home/michael/apps/myapp/current/public;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Application.css

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

Comment: In the production env you have to look for the `.css` files in `public/assets` dir, I doubt you'd be able to see it from the your browser. Can you post your `application.css` file?

Comment: Could you also post your `nginx.conf` file?

Comment: @jvperrin I added nginx.conf to the OP, however, I think the issue might have to do with the fact that the application.css file is renamed with the md5 hash on the end on the remote server.

Comment: @RumenMilushev I added application.css to the OP. However, note that it's renamed on the remote server which might be reason for the problem, although i don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @RumenMilushev the css file `http://162.XXX.XXX/assets/application-99190f98350e7ed3bb886d20f87bedfd.css` is listed in current/public/assets$

Comment: @rumenmilushev except it doesn't prefix the ip address etc

Comment: It is normal for deployed app to have renamed `application.*` files. It is interesting the way you are trying to include bootstrap's stylesheets (`=require twitter-bootstrap-static/bootstrap`) in the first css file in the OP. I think you have to add the lines `=require twitter-bootstrap-static/bootstrap` and `=require twitter-bootstrap-static/fontawesome` in your manifest file (`application.css`).

Comment: @Leahcim Try using `location ~ ^/(assets)/` instead of the `location ^~ /assets/` you have now. If that doesn't do anything, also try adding a root line in the assets location block: `root /home/michael/apps/myapp/current/public;`.

Comment: @RumenMilushev it is required in the manifest file. It works on local, so I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: @jvperrin I don't understand your comment

Comment: @Leahcim I meant to replace the line `location ^~ /assets/` in your nginx.conf file with `location ~ ^/(assets)/` instead. Also restart nginx after changing this.